# OpenVPN через SSH на Amazon EC2

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openvpn, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

Поднял OpenVPN на Ubuntu 14 ветки. Настроил iptables, форвардинг включен.
Если цепляюсь по OpenVPN с клиентов (windows/android), то всё ок - клиенты выходят в интернет и whoer определяет, что выход идет с серверов Amazon.

Теперь хочу завернуть весь траф через SSH. На нерутированном андройде единственный способ это сделать - пустить через VPN.

Для этого через **Putty/ConnectBot** настраиваю проброс портов `1194:localhost:1194`
В конфе OpenVPN клиента в **remote** пишу `localhost 1194`

OpenVPN успешно подключается через SSH, но выхода в интернет нет.
На Amazon разрешен весь траф. Порты открыты и не блокируются.

Не смог найти выход. Может что подскажете? Грешу на iptables, но не силен в нём.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему промежуточным хостом с windows+putty